# Get if user react page end with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, class

There are multiple answers to this question on Stackoverflow, however the most of them does not work for me, or are written in jQuery. How do I check if page bottom has been reached with vanilla JavaScript, and add / remove classes, based on this value? Perhaps, I should add some additional offset?

```
const ERROR_OFFSET = 10;
const TOP_MIN_OFFSET = 100;

const doc = document.body;
const offset = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset;
const height = doc.scrollHeight;

if (offset >= height) {
  // We are on the bottom. Does not always work =(
  document.documentElement.classList.remove('hideOnScroll');
  return;
}
```

Comment: Should this code be improved, or there is some other solution to the following one? What would be the enhancement, that always triggers if the page bottom has been reached

Comment: You could place a hidden div at the bottom of the page (say 1 pixel tall) and then detect it using an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: As @evolutionxbox said _IntersectionObserver_ is a good option or you can use `document.documentElement.clientHeight` to get the actual height of the viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

Comment: How would I go for the IntersectionObserver with React? Should I use refs to get the element, or how?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could try using window.scrollHeight instead of document

Here's my code below, it's similar but instead using 1 in the if statement, you could use 100.

```
window.onscroll = showBar;
const headerNav = document.getElementById(`headernav`);

   function showBar() {
   if (window.pageYOffset >= 1) {
    headerNav.classList.add(`scrolled`);
     } 
   else {
     headerNav.classList.remove(`scrolled`);
    }

   }
```